# How can I read a Snowflake session parameter into a variable?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to store the value of a session parameter in a variable, so I can change it, do some processing, then restore the original value.

I can get see the value I want to store with

```
show parameters like 'timezone';
```

But how do I store it in a variable?

Comment: I assume you're using Snowflake UI rather than a programmatic way from client side? If that's the case you can create a stored procedure like in this [example](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Stored-Procedure-To-Find-The-Value-Of-Parameter-CLIENT-SESSION-KEEP-ALIVE-For-A-Users-Or-At-The-Session-Level)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly but you can use resultscan and the last query id to read the specific values to a variable.
For eg:

```
show parameters like '%timezone%';
set var=(SELECT $2 FROM table(RESULT_SCAN('<query id for show command>')) where $1='TIMEZONE');
select $var;
```

Here, $1='TIMEZONE' corresponds to the row which I am looking for and $2 corresponds to the column value which needs to be stored in the variable.

Comment: Think the first $1 should be $2, but otherwise that seems to do the job.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to be able to read them directly, but the next best thing would be to set them in a session variable for easier reference in statements.

I decided to write a stored procedure to do exactly that. This SP takes two parameters, the prefix you'd like to apply to the SQL variable name (to help avoid name collisions), and the LIKE expression for the session parameter. If you want to set variables for all of them, send a blank string or % for that parameter.

```
create or replace procedure SESSION_PARAMETERS_TO_VARIABLES("variablePrefix" string, "likeFilter" string)
returns string
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$

if (likeFilter == "") likeFilter = "%";

class Query{constructor(statement){this.statement = statement;}}
let show = getQuery(`show parameters like '${escapeString(likeFilter)}'`);
let params = getQuery(`select "key", "value", "type" from table(result_scan('${show.statement.getQueryId()}'))`);

let i = 0;
while (params.resultSet.next()) {
    i++;
    if (params.resultSet.getColumnValue("type") == 'STRING') {
        getQuery(`set ${variablePrefix + params.resultSet.getColumnValue("key")} = '${escapeString(params.resultSet.getColumnValue("value"))}'`);
    } else {
        getQuery(`set ${variablePrefix + params.resultSet.getColumnValue("key")} = ${params.resultSet.getColumnValue("value")}`);
    }
}

return `Set ${i} session variables.`;


function getQuery(sql){
    cmd = {sqlText: sql};
    var query = new Query(snowflake.createStatement(cmd));
    query.resultSet = query.statement.execute();
    return query;
}

function escapeString(value) {
    var s = value.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
    s = s.replace(/'/g, "''" );
    s = s.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
    s = s.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
    return s;
}

$$;


call session_parameters_to_variables('params_', 'timezone'); -- Set a session variable called "params_timezone" with the timezone 
call session_parameters_to_variables('', 'timezone'); -- Also can set no profix, so the session variable is the same name as the session parameter.
call session_parameters_to_variables('params_', ''); --Leave the likeFilter blank or set to % to set variables for all session parameters. This will take ~7 seconds.
```